# zip AST with bool list

Tags: haskell, uniplate

I have an [`AST`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.16.0.1/docs/Language-Haskell-Exts-Syntax.html#t:Module) representing a haskell program and a bitvector/bool list representing the presence of strictness annotations on [`Pattern`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.16.0.1/docs/Language-Haskell-Exts-Syntax.html#t:Pat)s in order.For example, `1000` represents a program with 4 `Pat`s where the first one is a `BangPat`. Is there any way that I can turn on and off the annotations in the `AST` according to the list?

-- EDIT: further clarify what I want `editBang` to do

Based on user5042's answer: 
`Simple.hs :=`

```
main = do
  case args of
    [] -> error "blah"
    [!x] -> putStrLn "one"
    (!x : xs) -> putStrLn "many"
```

And I want `editBang "Simple.hs" [True, True, True, True]` to produce

```
main = do
  case args of
    [] -> error "blah"
    [!x] -> putStrLn "one"
    (!(!x : !xs)) -> putStrLn "many"
```

Given that above are the only 4 places that `!` can appear

Comment: Answer updated with working example.

Comment: Note that `!xs` is not allowed. You've got your work cut out for you since bangs are allowed in many locations that you are not considering, e.g. `![]` and `![!x]`, but they are not allowed at top-level definitions, e.g. `!main = ...` is not allowed even though `main` is a pattern. Next time be more explicit about what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a first step, here's how to use `transformBi`:

```
import Data.Data
import Control.Monad
import Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data
import Language.Haskell.Exts
import Text.Show.Pretty (ppShow)

changeNames x = transformBi change x
  where change (Ident str) = Ident ("foo_" ++ str)
        change x           = x

test2 = do
  content <- readFile "Simple.hs"
  case parseModule content of
    ParseFailed _ e -> error e
    ParseOk a       -> do
      let a' = changeNames a
      putStrLn $ ppShow a'
```

The `changeNames` function finds all occurrences of a `Ident s` and replaces it with `Ident ("foo_"++s)` in the source tree.

There is a monadic version called `transformBiM` which allows the replacement function to be monadic which would allow you to consume elements from your list of Bools as you found bang patterns.

Here is a complete working example:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data
import Language.Haskell.Exts
import Text.Show.Pretty (ppShow)
import Control.Monad.State.Strict

parseHaskell path = do
  content <- readFile path
  let mode = ParseMode path Haskell2010 [EnableExtension BangPatterns] False False Nothing
  case parseModuleWithMode mode content of
    ParseFailed _ e -> error $ path ++ ": " ++ e
    ParseOk a       -> return a

changeBangs bools x = runState (transformBiM go x) bools
  where go pp@(PBangPat p) = do
           (b:bs) <- get
           put bs
           if b
             then return p
             else return pp
        go x = return x

test = do
  a <- parseHaskell "Simple.hs"
  putStrLn $ unlines . map ("before: " ++) . lines $ ppShow a
  let a' = changeBangs [True,False] a
  putStrLn $ unlines . map ("after : " ++) . lines $ ppShow a'
```

You might also look into using `rewriteBiM`.

The file `Simple.hs`:

```
main = do
  case args of
    [] -> error "blah"
    [!x] -> putStrLn "one"
    (!x : xs) -> putStrLn "many"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't expecting a full answer like this. Will accept as soon as I get it working.